# Maven dependency convergence error (wrong version used)

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I've got this strange problem and I have no clue what's the problem.

I have a multi-module java maven project with a structure like this:

```
+ A (parent)
+-+-B
| +--C
| +--D
```

I added a dependency in the parent pom (A):

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

**Note**: Version 1.8.5 is necessary for other modules beside A

In modules C and D it is necessary to use version 2.3.0, so i override version 1.8.5 from parent pom A with this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I added this dependecy in the poms of module C and D.  C is also a dependency of D. So when i try to build the project, i get following error:

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence   failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:1.8.5 paths to dependency are:
+-de.xxx.xxx.xxx:module-D:6.40.1-jat-SNAPSHOT
  +-de.xxx.xxx.xxx:module-C:6.40.1-jat-SNAPSHOT
    +-org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:1.8.5
and
+-de.xxx.xxx.xxx:module-D:6.40.1-jat-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.3.0
```

So somehow maven thinks the version of quartz of Module C is 1.8.5 but i explicitly set the version in the pom of module C to 2.3.0

also when i run mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose in the directory of module C, it seems correct:
    [INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.0:compile

Does anybody has any idea?

Comment: Which ever the version you want to use or override, put it inside "dependencyManagement" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module A (the parent) must have a packaging type of `pom`.

In general **it is a bad idea to declare dependencies in parent poms** because it **forces all child modules to have these specific dependencies whether they are needed or not**. It is the equivalent of declaring these dependencies in every child module.

When modules C and D come into play you then have the equivalent of *duplicate dependency declarations with conflicting versions*.

Instead, module A should use a `<dependencyManagement>` section to declare dependency versions without forcing every child module to actually be dependent upon them.

In other words:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
           <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
           <version>1.8.5</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                  <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The quartz dependency declarations in modules C and D will then simply override the version specified in the parent A.

Other modules that are dependent upon the *managed* quartz library will still need to explicitly declare it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

where the `version` and `exclusions` will be picked up from the managed dependency declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Check dependency hierarchy of module C and exclude the version 1.8.5 (with modern IDE like eclipse, this should be easy). 
Or you may remove this dependency from parent pom, use it in dependency management, and in child module, indicate the version you'd like to use. Dependencies in parent pom will be inherited by all the children.